# $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is vector space over a residue field $k＝R/M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Let $（R,M）$ be a local ring.
I heard that $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is vector space over a residue field $k＝R/M$.

I would like to confirm this is true.

Firstly,
Could you tell me how we define map $k×M^n/M^{n+1}→M^n/M^{n+1}$ ？

I'll try to check axioms of vector space, if I get this map.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $M^n$ is an ideal of $R$, so $rx \in M^n$ for all $r \in R$ and $x \in M^n$. So given $r + M \in k$ and $x + M^{n+1} \in M^n/M^{n+1}$, define $(r+M) (x + M^{n+1} ) := rx + M^{n+1}$. Now you have to check that this map is well-defined, i.e., is independent of the choice of representatives $r$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of guessing how to define the scalar multiplication, try this:

Since $M^n/M^{n+1}$ is an $R$-module, the map $\mu : R \to \operatorname{End}_\textsf{Ab}(M^n/M^{n+1})$ given by $r \mapsto (x \mapsto rx)$ is a ring homomorphism. Now note that $M \subseteq \ker \mu$ (i.e. for any $m \in M$, $mx = 0$ for all $x \in M^n/M^{n+1}$), so $\mu$ factors through the quotient $k = R/M$, and then the induced map $\tilde \mu : k \to \operatorname{End}_\textsf{Ab}(M^n/M^{n+1})$ gives us the scalar multiplication!

Answer (score 0):

Try the case $n=1$.  The scalar multiplication of $R/M$ on $M/M^2$ is obvious: if $r+M$ is a scalar, and $m + M^2$ is a vector, their product is defined to be $rm+M^2$.